# The number of isomorphism classes for the symmetry group of 6 elements?

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism

The different isomorphism classes of subgroups of $S_3$ is:
trivial, $Z_2$, $Z_3$ and $S_3$ itself - that is $4$ different types

The number of isomorphism classes of subgroups of $S_4$ is $9$ and $S_5$ is $16$.

Do anyone know this number for $S_6$?

Comment: I was going to say "[Groupprops does](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S6#Quick_summary)!", but in fact they do not (or if they do, they're not telling). It is evidently at most $56$ (are you hoping it's $25$?)

Comment: GAP should be able to do this fairly easily. First ask for the conjugacy classes of the subgroups, then list the ID's of a representative of each, then convert to a set and take the size.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: One of the answers to the question I indicated as a duplicate used GAP :-) (The number is $29$, a few more than $25$.)

Comment: @joriki Ahh, nice (and it does it in very close to the way I described).

Comment: @jorki is the number $29$ or $\geq 29$?

Comment: I would recommend getting GAP so you can do the calculation yourself. It will be a good tool for similar problems later on as well.

Comment: @pjs36 I'm testing a pseudo isomorphism test and I admit I was a little bit curious about $25$ or not.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have GAP but I'm to old to learn such a complex system https://www.reddit.com/r/Forth/comments/45e55g/sick_and_tired_of_gap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often OEIS has the answer:

http://oeis.org/A174511

There are exactly 29 isomorphism types of subgroups of $S_6$.

Comment: Thank you! I found http://schmidt.nuigalway.ie/subgroups/s6.pdf as a reference of the arxiv paper in the first question to which mine is a duplicate, but have difficulties to understand this table.

Comment: The link (the OEIS entry) is simply a list of the numbers of isomorphism types of subgroups for different $n$, together with relevant links and references.